# Override samples and branched path tracing

Tags: rendering, render-layers

**Branched Path Tracing** provides *AA samples* and *multiplier samples* for different rays: diffuse, glossy, etc. So *Total sampling* for each ray is defined as AA*multiplier.

But what is renderlayer's **Override** samples in this case? Does it override *AA samples* only or *Total sample* number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Render Layer 'Override' setting overrides the AA samples.

For example, setting the render layer override to 300 while having Diffuse branched path tracing samples set to 5 will result in 1500 Diffuse samples.

One interesting point to note is how the override interacts with the Square Samples setting as it overrides *before* the squaring takes place - so setting Override to, say, 300 with Square Samples enabled will be equivalent to setting to 90000 without squaring enabled.